# Kurt Lewin's 3 stage change process: which stage has the most resistance?

Tags: change-management

Is there in Kurt Lewin's 3 stage change process ([Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Lewin#Change_process)) any "resistance distribution" or all stages have nearly equal resistance level? If so, which stage actually has the most resistance level?

Comment: Please clarify where you are trying to apply this theory.  Otherwise this sounds like a homework question.

Comment: @WBW this is only a theoretical question, no practice involved

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of Lewin discussed resistance anywhere in his work regarding his three stages; however, Kubler-Ross's stages of grief--http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCbler-Ross_model--have been expanded into the change resistance curve--[enter link description here](http://www.mindtools.com/pages/article/newPPM_96.htm)--that is often used on transformation type projects.  This would suggest that the greatest degree of resistance, stages two through four on Kubler-Ross's model, might be consistent with the second stage of Lewin's model.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the linked article states, in the first phase "defense mechanisms have to be bypassed", which to me seems to suggest overcoming resistance.

I actually prefer the model described by William Bridges in "Managing Transitions". It has three phases that sound quite similar, but have a much more compassionate focus on helping people deal with their emotions regarding a change, rather than "dismantling a mindset".